# C# web scraping que tem SilverLight

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, silverlight

Estou fazendo um web `scraping`, consegui automatizar até certa parte, porém quando chega em um certo momento, o Site abre o Silverlight,então a partir dai não consigo pegar mais nenhum valor para fazer a raspagem de dados.

Gostaria de dicas de pacotes ou como eu posso fazer para chegar até o caminho que necessito, já procurei na internet alguns tutoriais, porém sem sucesso, vi um tal de 'Silverniun' entretanto não consegui utilizá-lo, ou utilizei de maneira incorreta. Agradeço a ajuda.

```
            // ENTRA NA ABA BIBLIOTECA.
        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Biblioteca de documentos")).Click();


        // ENTRA NO FRAME 
        driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Id("MyIframe")));

        // SILVERLIGHT
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("silverlightControlHost")).Click();
```

a partir dai entra o Silverlight, que não deixa eu pegar Name, ID, Classe, qualquer coisa do Gênero

Comment: Apresente o seu código, sem ter um  [MCVE] não tem como ajudar de alguma forma...

Comment: Adicionei uma parte do meu código, porém eu quero saber como posso pegar, classe, nome ou id do SilverLight, pois apos ele abrir eu teria que clicar em "VSA" e depois "ServiceDesk", que estão em uma Treeview dentro do Silverlight

Comment: dê uma lida nisso daqui http://www.lcss.net/silverlight/Silverlight_object_models.htm#Silverlight_Object_Model